# Reports are not accessable from one of web fron ends @ Sharepoint Farm (I can send the snapshots)

Tags: sharepoint-2007, reportserver, web-frontend

We have a report server in Sharepoint Farm but when users try to connect from one of WFE, they receive HTTP 401 error but it works fine with other WFE.
We have 2 Web front ends (WFE) in the farm, PROD_MOSS01 and PROD_MOSS02. Those 2 servers are load balanced by our firewall (Forefront TMG). 
A client connects to forefront, then it sends the traffic to one of the WFE, & uses the external host name. The 2 WFEs are now configured to use a new single report server, PROD_REPORT. The report service is joined to the farm, and is setup to not display web content. It was configured in SP Integrated mode, but it keeps defaulting to native mode. 
If I drop the report DB and re-attach, it shows the DB is SP Integrated mode. When it attaches, it reverts back to Native.
So with this setup, only 1 WFE is able to generate reports. Initially it was PROD_MOSS01 that was working, and PROD_MOSS02 was throwing the 401 error. Now it seems to have switched which one works and which throws the error. So it looks like only 1 WFE can connect to the report sever, the other cannot.
We have the farm/report server setup to use NTLM only, but if this is a limitation of NTLM authentication, we can try & get Kerberos configured. I have not registered the SPNs for the new report sever.
Also, if you hit the server with the 401 error, you cannot configure the DM_MRCS connection string. It gives an error saying the Report server must be in SP integrated mode and attached to the farm.